# BlackBerry application crashes when i install it on my blackberry bold 9700?

Tags: blackberry

The error I get is that class net.rim.device.api.ui.ScrollView is not found. All I am using in application are some fields:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.CheckboxField;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ObjectChoiceField;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.SeparatorField;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.FontFamily;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Ui;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compile your application with right version that you have installed on your blackberry device.Similar error that you can look at [here](http://support.dataviz.com/support.srch?docid=14297)

Answer (score 2):

[ScrollView](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/ScrollView.html) was introduced in the 6.0 API and so it is not available on devices running earlier operating systems, such as the 9700 running 5.0.

Comment: I dont think I am using ScrollView. What can i take off to not use it?

Comment: @jini compile for version 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Compile your application with the 5.0 plugin/JDE and not 6.0.

Comment: I tried doing that with a 4.7 and I am still getting it. The imports I have are: import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;