# Torch and other old versions compatible problem

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-torch

I developed an application with simulator 4.6 and 5.0 then a couple of weeks later, today I finished the Torch version of my application (JDE 6.0 and simulator 9800)

My application works great with Torch but for the other older versions I got a

`class net.rim.device.api.ui.ScrollView` error.

I googled and found some advices like a "try with JDE 5.0 or stg else" but I didn't work.

So how can I solve my problem? Is it possible for a application to works with every model of BlackBerry Device?

Comment: If you take a look at the documentation for ScrollView, it says Since BlackBerry API 6.0.0, so it would not work in an older version:  http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/ScrollView.html

Comment: Yeah I know but I didnt even use it. I just add some codes about the reseloution thats it. and please check it same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674327/blackberry-application-crashes-when-i-install-it-on-my-blackberry-bold-9700

Answer (score 1):

The ScrollView is not part of the API before version 6.0.

You will have to use a normal view(Manager) and send in the property to use scroll.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/VerticalFieldManager.html

> Behaviour A vertical field manager
>   lays out fields top to bottom in a
>   single column. You can build this
>   manager with Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL
>   to accommodate fields wider than the
>   manager's visible frame; you can build
>   this manager with
>   Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL to accommodate
>   collections of fields taller than the
>   manager's visible frame.

Comment: Yeah thanks for you response but I dont use "class net.rim.device.api.ui.ScrollView" Here is the list:import com.aveasport.client.AveaSportApp;

import com.aveasport.controller.UiManager;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.Browser;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Ui;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

Comment: @eddie1907, You probably compiled your app with SDK version 6 instead of version 5. A version 5 compiled app will work on a version 6 OS, but not the other way around.

Comment: yeah you right it's too diffucult for me firstly I will check for Torch and then change sdk and then try for others.. Thanks anyway. Appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [BlackBerry Preprocessor](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Use-the-preprocessor/ta-p/445231), and generate a build for each version of BlackBerry OS you support.